# Javascript replace, ignore the first match

Tags: javascript

I have the following script in javascript

```
var idText;
var idText1;
idText = "This_is_a_test";
idText1 = idText.replace(/_/g, " ");
alert(idText1);
```

When I show idText1, it replaces all of the underscores and puts in a space where they were.  However, I am trying to keep the very first underscore, so I get "This_is a test".  Is this possible at all?

Comment: use a callback instead of space as a second parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is certainly possible, here is one option:

```
var n = 0;
idText1 = idText.replace(/_/g, function($0) {
    n += 1;
    return n === 1 ? $0 : " ";
});
```

This uses a callback for the replacement that increments a counter for each match, and replaces the first match with the original text by checking the value of that counter.

Comment: When I try this, the alert popup says "undefined"

Comment: Try it now, I was just showing the replacement without assigning the result back to the `idText1` variable.