# How to replace all matching characters except the first occurrence

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, string-matching

I am trying to use regex to compare a string in JavaScript. I want to replace all `'.'s` and `'%'s` with empty character '' but the catch is I don't want to replace the first occurrence of `'.'`.

```
value.replace(/\%\./g, '');
```

Expected result like below:

```
.4.5.6.7. ==> .4567
4.5667.444... ==> 4.56667444
..3445.4 ==> .34454
```

Comment: Replace the first `.` with something unique of your choice, then replace it back later?

Comment: hmm i would prefer a robust solution rather than like a hack for now. If there is not other way. I would definetley adapt your suggestion. Thank you @tuananh

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript replace, ignore the first match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643448/javascript-replace-ignore-the-first-match)

Comment: @RahulDess I came back and added a self-contained version with no external variables. Please see my additional answer.

Comment: Thanks @Drakes ..seen your update.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can pass in a function to `replace`, and skip the first match like this:

```
var i = 0;
value.replace(/[\.\%]/g, function(match) { 
    return match === "." ? (i++ === 0 ? '.' : '') : ''; 
});
```

---

Here is a self-contained version with no external variables:

```
value.replace(/[\.\%]/g, function(match, offset, all) { 
   return match === "." ? (all.indexOf(".") === offset ? '.' : '') : ''; 
})
```

This second version uses the `offset` passed into the `replace()` function to compare against the index of the first `.` found in the original string (`all`). If they are the same, the regex leaves it as a `.`. Subsequent matches will have a higher offset than the first `.` matched, and will be replaced with a `''`. `%` will always be replaced with a `''`.

---

Both versions result in:

> 4.5667.444... ==> 4.56667444
>   %4.5667.444... ==> 4.5667444

Demo of both versions: [http://jsbin.com/xuzoyud/5/](http://jsbin.com/xuzoyud/5/edit?js,console)

Comment: That doesn't quite seem like it works. Providing a value of "45% and 45.6" results in "45. and 456"

Comment: Added a self-contained version with no external variables. Both work fine.

Comment: That second version seems inefficient, doing an `.indexOf()` every time. (Presumably not noticeable on such short input strings, but might matter for long strings.)