# Replace all except first

Tags: javascript, regex

Is it possible to replace all occurrences except the first one?
So `123.45.67..89.0` should become `123.4567890`.

Edit: I'm looking for a regex.
I know how to do it with concat or using the index.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30227218/5241603

Answer (score 11):

You could use a positive lookbehind to achieve this:

```
(?<=\..*)\.
```

So your code would be

```
"123.45.67..89.0".replace(/(?<=\..*)\./g, '');
```

Comment: This is not supported in Safari (v14.1 at time of writing)

Comment: This could BREAK the entire website on iphone

Answer (score 7):

Using JS:

```js
var str = "123.45.67.89.0";

var firstOccuranceIndex = str.search(/\./) + 1; // Index of first occurance of (.)

var resultStr = str.substr(0, firstOccuranceIndex) + str.slice(firstOccuranceIndex).replace(/\./g, ''); // Splitting into two string and replacing all the dots (.'s) in the second string

console.log(resultStr);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This is correct and it works. I think `indexOf` might be less expensive instead of `search`. I'm looking for a regex solution.

Answer (score 2):

I know OP asks for solutions with regex, but for others here's an alternative solution using `String.prototype.split()` and `Array.prototype.reduce()`:

```
function replaceAllExceptFirst(str, search, replace) {
  return str
    .split(search)
    .reduce((prev, curr, i) => prev + (i == 1 ? search : replace) + curr);
}
```

For this example, one would use this function like this:

```
replaceAllExceptFirst('123.45.67..89.0', '.', '')
```

In my case, I needed to replace all occurrences of a given substring except for the last one. For this, only a small modification is necessary:

```
function replaceAllExceptLast(str, search, replace) {
  return str
    .split(search)
    .reduce(
      (prev, curr, i, substrs) =>
        prev + (i !== substrs.length - 1 ? replace : search) + curr
    );
}
```

I am aware that using regex might be more efficient. Just thought that maybe this is easier to understand for folks like me who still can't really wrap their head around regex.

PS: This is my first post on StackOverflow, so please be kind :)

Answer (score 2):

Use slice to skip the first character in your string and then replace all the occurrences of `-` with blanks.

```
let str = "-11-1---111----1--"
str.slice(0, 1) + str.slice(1).replaceAll('-', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

Would this be cheating:

```
"123.45.67.89.0".replace(/\..*/, c => "." + c.replace(/\./g, () => ""))
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it with a single regex?

Comment: I am skeptical doing this with a single regex and a join would be possible in Javascript because of limitations on the way Javascript handles nested groups.

Answer (score 1):

We can pass a function to the replace method and match all occurance except the first one. Something like this -

> `givenString.replace(/{pattern_here}/g, (item) => (!index++ ? item : ""));`

```js
const givenString = '123.45.67..89.0'
let index = 0

let result = givenString.replace(/\./g, (item) => (!index++ ? item : ""));

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I like this one. I just did it the same myself and wanted to post it. Then I noticed this answer :D BTW, you can also use [`replaceAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) and just pass `"."` string (no need for regex object).

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
var a = '123.45.67.89.0';

a.split('.')[0].concat('.'+a.split('.')[1]+a.split('.')[2]+a.split('.')[3]+a.split('.')[4])
```

Comment: You don't think `a.split(".")[0] + "." + a.split(".").slice(1).join("")` might be a bit more general (and readable)?

Comment: yes you are right my approach is bit lengthy... in hurry i coulnot think about this approach

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about *length*.  Worry that (1) it's not general (suppose there were five dots, or 100), and (2) the code is [repetitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), which is ripe for errors.

Comment: yes, but i had given answer considering the input given...sir your method is generalised and can be used for any large numbers, from next tym i will give answers considering the other inputs also..thanks for your guidance

Comment: This is not general enough and it wouldn't work with `123.44.3`, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps splice() is more suited for this.

```
var str = "123.45.67.89.0";
var arr = str.split(".");
var ans = arr.splice(0,2).join('.') + arr.join('');

alert(ans);
// 123.4567890
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first find the first occurrence of the `.` using [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) and then using [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) you can return what is returned and replaced with a matching string.

```js
const str = "123.45.67..89.0";
const firstOccurence = str.indexOf(".");
const result = str.replace(/\./g, (...args) => {
  if (args[1] === firstOccurence) return args[0];
  else return "";
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
var str="123.45.67.89.0";
var arr=str.split(".");
var ans=[];
ans=arr.map(function(a,index){
return a + (index?"":".");
})
console.log(ans.join().replace (/,/g, ""));
```

Comment: That is **not** the way to use `map()`.  You should write `arr.map(function(a,index) { return a + (index?"":".")})`.

Comment: And, it is **not** the way to join an array.  Use `.join("")`.

Comment: @Malvolio that's ok . but i am getting answer as he wanted

Comment: It is **not** OK! Getting the right answer in one limited case is the tiniest bit of engineering.

Comment: Edit the join too!